# R tableGrob plot numbers in scientific notation in plotmath

Tags: r, gridextra, plotmath

I'd like to plot a table in R using tableGrob containing numbers which should display in scientific notation in math mode, such as 2.45x10⁵.

I tried using `format(x,scientific=TRUE)` but it only displays as 2.45e+5. If I pass `theme=ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(parse=TRUE)))`, it discards formatting for some numbers and just shows plain decimal number.

```
library(gridExtra)
x<-matrix(c(4.5*10^-5,2.33*10^5))
tt<-ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(parse=TRUE)))
plot(tableGrob(format(x,scientific=TRUE),theme=tt))
```

The output shows:

```
4.5e-05
233000
```

I'd rather want:

```
4.50×10⁻⁵
2.33×10⁵
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping for more elegant solution than the solution given in the duplicate question. I can see that plot actually shows math number format for labels, so there must have been mechanism already in place to show the math number format for any non-label values, either thru plotmath or some built-in mechanism.